# ListView Items change position on scroll

Tags: android, listview

I have Implemented a ListView which loads news, but news changes position when I scroll the list. this is list

```
public class ListNewsFragment extends SherlockListFragment{

private ListNewsAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mAdapter = new ListNewsAdapter(this, app.getAllNews());
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}


public class ListNewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private List<News> news;
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ViewHolder holder;

public ListNewsAdapter(final Fragment c, List<News> news) {
    super();
    this.news = news;
    this.mContext = c.getActivity();
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {               
         inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);         
         holder = new ViewHolder();
         v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_news, null);

         holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tittle);
         holder.tweet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.news);
         holder.avatar = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);


         holder.name.setText(news.get(position).getTitulo());
         holder.tweet.setText(news.get(position).getCopete());
         new ImagefetcherTask(position).execute(holder);

         v.setTag(holder);
    } else {              
     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();          
     }                             
   return v; 

}

private class ViewHolder{
    public TextView name, tweet;
    public ImageView avatar;
}

private class ImagefetcherTask extends AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, ViewHolder> {

        private Bitmap bitmap;
        int position; 

        public ImagefetcherTask(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        protected ViewHolder doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
             ViewHolder viewHolder = params[0];

            try{
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL("...."+ news.get(position).getImagen().toString()).getContent());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

          return viewHolder;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ViewHolder result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (bitmap == null) {
            result.avatar.setImageResource(com.dev.suma_intranet_v1.R.drawable.img_perfil);
        } else {
            result.avatar.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: you only set text to textview when view is null and better use lazy loading for loading images. also cache them so you don't have to download evertime

Comment: @Raghunandan how should I do it?

Comment: move set to text code after else statement in getView method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your `getView()` method to this:

```
Map<Integer, View> views = new HashMap<Integer, View>;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (views.containsKey(position)) {    
         return views.get(position);
    }

     inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);         
     holder = new ViewHolder();
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_news, null);

     holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tittle);
     holder.tweet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.news);
     holder.avatar = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);

     holder.name.setText(news.get(position).getTitulo());
     holder.tweet.setText(news.get(position).getCopete());
     new ImagefetcherTask(position).execute(holder);

     v.setTag(holder); 
     views.put(position, v);
     return v; 

}
```

Comment: If I do that the images keep changing

Comment: That's because of your `ImagefotherTask`. Can you add code for it? My guess is that it updates images after you scrolled and reused the `View`. If you have a limited amount of items in the list then you can stop reusing the `View` and it should solve the issue. You might want to consider storing all `View`s in a `List`.

Comment: That´s all the code I have for it, and yes I have 30 items, how do I stop reusing the view?

Comment: I have updated the code. Comment if stmh is unclear.

Comment: contains is undefined  for Map

Comment: Sorry about that, it's `containsKey()`.

Comment: how should I instantiate the Map?

Comment: Either in your `onCreate()` method or like it's done in the my suggested code.

Comment: @IgnacioGarat how did you solve it? The above code makes the list neverending for me and it keeps on scrolling both ways

Comment: @IgnacioGarat Thanks for your response. 
The above code does not work for me. I mean the images dont swap but The listview gets totally messed up. Endless scrolling distorted view ..whatnot. .Did you change something else as well?

Comment: @MukulGoel have you overwritten the other methods? getCount, getItem, etc? I have added a DiskLRUCache and I'm saving images in cache.

Comment: @IgnacioGarat : yes, i have overridden the methods and I am using a cache but I am using a `softReference` `HashMap` to maintain cache

Comment: @MukulGoel it seem that the problem is in the adapter, are you using the position parameter of the getView and sending it to the cache as well?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52061/discussion-between-mukul-goel-and-ignacio-garat)

Comment: Consider up voting so the answer would be more visible to others.

Comment: As far as I know, views are expensive to create. If I was to write the answer now, I'd really use the views rather than just caching them. That way the code would only use as many view objects as it can fit on the screen without creating new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Call your `ImageFetcher` and `TextView.seText` after your `else` statement so that when the `convertView` isn't `null` and has been recycled, you're updating your row:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_news, null);

        holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tittle);
        holder.tweet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.news);
        holder.avatar = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.name.setText(news.get(position).getTitulo());
    holder.tweet.setText(news.get(position).getCopete());
    new ImagefetcherTask(position).execute(holder);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Please also write some explanation so that he have better understanding of Recycling/Reusability of `Views` in `TableView`

Comment: @adneal If I do that the images keep changing

Comment: @IgnacioGarat That's probably related to your `ImageFetcher`.

Comment: @IgnacioGarat You aren't checking to see if the item has been recycled. You should read: [Making ListView Scrolling Smooth](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) on the Android Developers website.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this by overriding these two methods in my adapter class.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
   return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do lazy load an image by using [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) Universal image loader library. and try to catch image.

so as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340127/fast-scroll-in-listview-optimizing-using-universalimageloader-or-using-reference/21340268#21340268) answer set the bitmap options as

```
DisplayImageOptions  options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                        .cacheInMemory(true)
                        .cacheOnDisc(true)
                        .considerExifParams(true)
                        .build();
```

I am sure this will solve your problem